# Can I use the indicator icons from Ubuntu Touch on the desktop version?

Tags: themes, icons, ubuntu-touch

I am re-theming my Ubuntu 13.04 laptop to use an interface which looks more like that of Ubuntu Touch. One of the last things I need to complete the look are the indicator icons being used in Ubuntu Touch's top panel. Is there a way I can get these icons and use them instead in Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Files should be somewhere in `/usr/share/themes`.

Comment: Could you possibly add a screenshot of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get these icons and use them instead in Ubuntu 13.04?

Yes, first you need to install the icons:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mobile-icons
```

Then go to the folder   `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mobile-icons/status` and copy the icons you want.

Then rename and replace the icons in other icon theme for example in Humanity or ubuntu-mono-light/dark.

Comment: Yep, this works! It's worth noting that I had to copy those icons into `ubuntu-mono-dark`'s `16`, `22` and `24` directories to get it to work. But now they're there and they look great. :)