# Is there an ubuntu desktop icon theme that looks like ubuntu touch icons?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, themes, icons

The question is clear. Is there an ubuntu desktop icon theme (complete or not) that looks like ubuntu touch icons?

I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294978/can-i-use-the-indicator-icons-from-ubuntu-touch-on-the-desktop-version), and on trying to install the ubuntu-mobile-icons, I got this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-mobile-icons
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Donarsson 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ubuntu-mobile-icons`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/gnome/ubuntu-mobile-icons) package looks like it is available only for Ubuntu 13.04 or later.

I think you can just download the .deb file from the above link and install it - since these are icons, I doubt there will be an issue.

You should be able to use these commands to get the version for `saucy` 13.10:

```
wget http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/ubuntu-themes/ubuntu-mobile-icons_13.04+13.10.20131014-0ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo gedbi ubuntu-mobile-icons_13.04+13.10.20131014-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

<sup>I will add I can install the above version using `apt-get` *(I'm using 13.10)*, the problem is icons like the one for the menu, or the one for the network settings don't seem to be included....</sup>

---

Alternatively, if you want to download and extract the icons:

```
mkdir mobile-icons; cd mobile-icons
wget http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/ubuntu-themes/ubuntu-mobile-icons_13.04+13.10.20131014-0ubuntu1_all.deb
ar x ubuntu-mobile-icons_13.04+13.10.20131014-0ubuntu1_all.deb
tar -xf data.tar.gz
```

This will download & extract extract the icons to `./mobile-icons/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mobile`

Comment: Instead of a .deb file, is there like a zip file I can extract and maybe choose individually the icons I want? Or how can I extract (not install) a .deb file?

Comment: added to answer - Note if you have already downloaded it, you can just run the last two commands if the terminal is in the same folder as the downloaded .deb

Comment: Thanxs @wilf. RUn the commands just fine.